# Cannot start Intellij on Ubuntu 14.04 with JDK 1.8

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, intellij

I recently installed JDK 1.8. When I try to run Intellij using the `idea.sh` script I get the following error:

```
Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_80-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required.
```

The puzzling thing is that I *do* have v1.8 of Java installed. This is the output of `java -version`:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when I uninstalled OpenJDK, and installed the latest JDK from Oracle. You'll need to change the JDK IntelliJ is configured to use. Check out this post for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk

It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.